# How to avoid Rest API abuse in Android?

Tags: android, rest, authentication, hmac

We have developed a service with REST APIs and an Android app that leverages it. We currently don't require our users to authenticate.

We would like to implement a simple mechanism to prevent the random person from invoking the APIs from outside of the scope of the app, mainly to avoid abuses that would spoil the data that we compute.

I stumbled upon [this url](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/) where they suggest to have authentication enforced by having the server and Android client to share a secret and use that to compute an **HMAC** to pass along with the request. They claim that they use this approach in Amazon (I have no experience with Amazon AWS yet).

I'm considering to proceed as follows:

- store a common secret in the Server and in the Android app (any good idea for obfuscating it, besides using ProGuard?)
- Have client and server to communicate over plain HTTP (we don't need  confidentiality yet and we will save some CPU) and use the HMAC method to authenticate the calls as "coming from a legitimate Android client".
- From time to time we can update the secret (perhaps at each new version of the app).
- If in future we will need confidentiality we will enable TLS for the relevant REST calls.

Do you think that this solution would work? Is anyone using something like this? Alternatives? Advices?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Counter-spoiling role have data checks on interface entry. 2. You have to use full security or You may left the problem and save many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I am not a security expert.*

Your solution sounds fine to protect you from "the random person", but you are still vulnerable to a dedicated attacker. Anything stored on the client can be dug out and used against you. ProGuard will dissuade a casual attacker, but against a dedicated attacker it's just a speed bump.

Nobody here is going to be able to tell you if that level of security is good enough, because it depends a lot on the specifics of your application. The final decision should rest with the product owner.

Comment: The goal is to put a mild protection, to stop whoever is not truly committed into hacking the app. For sure if we needed to ensure authentication at a strong(er) level we would use OAuth or TLS+User authentication with no secret embedded in the app itself. I personally like this solution because it doesn't require HTTPS (we don't need to hide the content passed around) and it is hard enough to break to discourage most of people.